# How to use two-way-databinding between controller and directive using AngularJS and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to outsource my table with their filter and sort functions as a directive.
Since I want to use two-way-databinding I am doing this:

```
public bindToController = {
      cars: "="
};
```

This is because when clicking in the table on a car, I am changing a property of this car and I need the controller where `cars` comes from to be aware of this.

```
export class CarsTableDirectiveController implements ng.IComponentController {
    public cars;


    public $onInit() {
        console.log(this.cars);
    }
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.cars);
    }

}


export class CarsTable implements ng.IDirective {

    public restrict: string = "E";
    public scope = {};
    public controller = CarsTableDirectiveController;
    public controllerAs: string = '$ctrl';
    public bindToController = {
        cars: "="
    };

    static instance(): ng.IDirective {
        return new CarsTable();
    }

    template: string = require<string>('./cars-table.html');

}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
<projects-table cars="ctrl.cars"></projects-table>
```

The cars data is shown in the table, but when I log `cars` it's always undefined.
What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve a two-way-databinding of the object `cars` and use the variable `cars` in `CarsTableDirectiveController`?

Comment: Can you show how you are using this directive?

Comment: Sorry, just added it.

Comment: Are the cars available right away? Or do they come from an AJAX call?

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. It worked, but $onInit() was triggered before the objects where completely loaded. My fault. Thank you!

Comment: Great, I figured this was the case so I added an answer. You can use `ng-if` to wait to create your directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, which makes me think the cars just aren't available right away (do they come from an AJAX call?). Thus when `constructor` and `$onInit` fire, the cars aren't there yet.

You can use `ng-if` to wait until cars exist to create your directive:

```
<projects-table ng-if="cars.length" cars="cars"></projects-table>
```

Now you should see the cars when `$onInit` fires (but not necessarily when `constructor` fires).

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem.